# VBScript not executed at the end of installation

Tags: vbscript, installshield

I've created an install package using InstallShield in Visual Studio 2015.

I've also created a script that should run after the installation.

Here's the code of this script (sorry for italian comments):

```
'Recupero la proprietà INSTALLDIR
Dim curfolder
curfolder = Session.Property("INSTALLDIR")


'CREO LA CARTELLA DB
Dim oFSO, objFolder
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (oFSO.FileExists(curfolder & "\DB\EnercomContext.sdf")) Then

    'Cancello il Database dalla cartella dell'installer
    oFSO.DeleteFolder(curfolder & "\Database")

Else

    Dim WshShell

    'Copio L'icona nella directory windows
    Set WshShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run ("xcopy """ & curfolder & "\Icon\icona_enercom.ico""" & " " & """C:\Windows\icona_enercom.ico""")

    'Creo la cartella
    Set objFolder = oFSO.CreateFolder(curfolder + "\DB")

    'Sposto il File di DB all'interno della cartella
    oFSO.MoveFile  curfolder & "\Database\EnercomContext.sdf", curfolder & "\DB\EnercomContext.sdf"

    oFSO.DeleteFolder(curfolder & "\Database")

End If
```

The problem is that this script is not executed even if it's correctly referenced in InstallShield. I've tried the installation on a Windows 10 PC, and the installer ask to me to give administrative rights.

Any suggestion why the script is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention administrative rights, I'm assuming this is not a per-user installation, and INSTALLDIR is typically in a per-machine location. In order to get the required privileges during your action, you need to schedule it deferred in system context (or commit in system context). However, doing so will lose access to the property INSTALLDIR, so you will have to use [CustomActionData](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?120824-CustomActionData-and-VBscript-HOW) to retrieve it.

Then you may run into a problem that you are not hosted by CScript or WScript, so references to WScript methods may not work (I think your `CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` is okay, but its use may be better implemented with the `FileSystemObject`).

Note that I do not recommend the use of VBScript custom actions, as they are prone to unusual failures.